# how to test a json response from spring Mvc controller with ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

i'm trying to test an `ajax` code that retreives `json` response from controller

this is my `spring controller`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody List<User> jsonresponse(Model model) {
 model.addAttribute("user", new User());
 List<User> l= new ArrayList<User>();
   l=this.userService.getUserList();
 return l;
 }
```

this is what the url `/json` in the browser shows  :
(data is retreived from database)

```
 [{"time":"11:01:00","val1":123,"val2":124,"val3":11,"val4":140,"val5":100},
```

{"time":"11:11:00","val1":140,"val2":100,"val3":13,"val4":100,"val5":120}]

I want to test an ajax code that extracts data from json and display it in the jsp page . I've tried this code but nothing is shown !

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType : 'JSON',
url: "/json",
data: ,
success :function(json) {
alert( json.time , json.val1) ;

}
});
```

I'm new with ajax and json . If there are some mistakes please tell me.

Comment: try hitting direct URL in browser, if it is working then place the correct URL here `url: "/json"`, if still not working then press **F12** in your browser and see if any javascript errors coming. - you can use $.get() method instead $.ajax for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code, remove the line:

```
data: ,
```

To avoid these kind of errors open the developer console in your browser and check if it shows any errors.